# message box control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to create a control just like a message box but trying that with a canvas or a grid doesn't satisfy my purpose as the controls behind those grid/canvas will be still active. Using a about prompt as in case of controls from coding4fun doesn't seem to suit either as i want to display some message only. How to create a control in such cases where all other controls should be disabled. Disabling all will be tedious task either.

**EDIT**

All i want is a modal control which is like a message box control. Popup gives me a modeless control. The control beneath it can be accessed when like popup is displayed.

Comment: Have you tried with a Popup control? Just set the background property so controls behind aren't visible

Comment: What about 'CustomMessageBox' from the Windows Phone Toolkit? Try downloading and modifying the [source from the sample app](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797)

Comment: Does PopUp control have a background property ? I don't see it. @KooKiz

Comment: @max if it doesn't, just put a grid in it and set the grid's background property. The grid will automatically fill the whole popup.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement MessageBox in Windows Phone is using Popup class. CustomMessageBox doesn't work very well on Windows Phone 8.

Here the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Popup class doesn't work like a message box. I have just tried and this works similar to a canvas or otherwise.